# How to substring concerning many delimiters in between

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split, substring

If i have string like this :

```
 String JSLines =  "DefineEvent(20140208,'Starting of Study for (old and new) student's ','','',17,5)";
```

How to get the following result like this :

```
20140208|Starting of Study for (old and new) student's
```

I try to do this :

```
 strDate = JSLines.Substring(JSLines.LastIndexOf("(") + 1, 8);
 toolTip = JSLines.Substring(JSLines.IndexOf(',') + 2, (JSLines.IndexOf(',', JSLines.IndexOf(',') + 1)) - (JSLines.IndexOf(',') + 3));
```

but it fails when i face `'` or `(` in my second parameter

Comment: What is the string? I don't know `DefineEvent`, what does it return?

Comment: @TimSchmelter : sorry i edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string methods only:

```
String JSLines = "DefineEvent(20140208,'Starting of Study for (old and new) student's ','','',17,5)";

string result = JSLines;
int methodBodyStart = JSLines.IndexOf("DefineEvent(");
if (methodBodyStart >= 0)
{
    methodBodyStart += "DefineEvent(".Length;
    int methodBodyEnd = JSLines.LastIndexOf(')');
    if (methodBodyEnd >= 0)
    {
        string methodBody = JSLines.Substring(methodBodyStart, methodBodyEnd - methodBodyStart);
        var twoParams = methodBody.Split(',')
           .Select(str => str.Trim(' ', '\'')).Take(2);
        result = string.Join("|", twoParams);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/wMGEXV)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
var substring = string.Join("|", "".Split(',').Take(2).Select(x => x.Trim('\'')));
```

of course this will work only if strings does not contain `,`, but in this case they're not

Comment: This will also include opening `'` and closing `'` which the OP do not want

Comment: the second parameter may include `,`

Comment: @just_name in that case it's not possible, because you have `'` and `,` in your string how do you think it is possible to determine end of string?

Comment: @wudzik :`unknown method Select(?)`

Comment: @just_name add `using System.Linq;` and change trim to actual version from answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var str = "DefineEvent(20140208,'Starting of Study for (old and new) student's ','','',17,5)";
        var arr = str.Split(new[] {",'","',", "DefineEvent(" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var result = String.Join("|", new[] {arr[1], arr[2]});
```